# How can I build a UserControl that uses tags instead of attributes to set properties?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms, asp.net-4.0

I have several sections of markup in a report that look like this:

```
<div class="report-section span-24 last">
    <h3 class="section-header">
        Municipal Valuation</h3>
    <p class="section-desc">
        <img src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Images/info-icon.png")%>' class="left" alt="Section Description" />
        The <strong>Municipal Valuation</strong> is the valuation provided by the relevant
        municipality and represents the market value assessed for rates purposes as at the
        date of valuation.</p>
</div>
```

I would like to create a user control that encapsulates everything that is the same in each section, so that I can instead define my sections like this:

```
<lsReport:Section ID="reportDetails" runat="server" Title="Transfer Information">
    <Description>The <strong>Municipal Valuation</strong> is the valuation provided by the relevant
    municipality and represents the market value assessed for rates purposes as at the
    date of valuation.</Description>
</lsReport:Section>
```

So that the title is always in a `<h3 class="section-header">` and the description paragraph always has the image, etc.  How do I go about this?  I can already define the Description text in an attribute on the control, but some descriptions are long, and contain markup. I would like to know how to set the control's Description property using the Description child element of the control element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can accomplish what you are trying to do with a custom templated user control.

```
<uc:lstReport id="report1" Title="somevalue" runat="server">    
      <Description>    
           Some custom content you want rendered in the desc.    
      </Description>    
      <ItemTemplate>    
           Here is a calendar: <asp:calendar id="cal1" runat="server" />    
      </ItemTemplate>    
   </uc:lstReport>
```

Check out [this](http://robseder.wordpress.com/2009/01/10/how-to-create-templated-asp-net-controls/) link as a starter.

Comment: Thanks @coder, +1 for a step in the right direction, but it looks like I have to build a templated *server* control, not user control, to include data binding in this arrangement.